# Getting class addresses on reading a file java

Tags: java, readfile

The code below reads from a file. The file contains around 3000 lines with 193 digits separated by space in each line.

void read(){

```
    String fileName = "ocr_train.txt";
    String line = null;
    float[] vertices = new float[200];

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);

            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
                if(parts[i] != null && parts[i].length() > 0){
                    vertices[i] = Float.parseFloat(parts[i]);
                }
            }
            Points p = new Points(vertices);
            System.out.println(p);
            full.add(p);
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
```

Here, when I try printing p, it gives me values like Points@10bf683, Points@d322f5 etc
What is wrong with this step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Check your Points class to have the toString() method or not. If not, please override it and print what you want inside it. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Point is a user defined class and contains a reference to vertices array, we need to override `toString()` method in Point `class` (in order for `System.out.println()` method to show some meaningful value as the default one shows `HashCode` of the `object`). Implementation of `toString()` would look like this:

```
public class Point {

    int[] vertices;
    //other code
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(null != vertices){
            return Arrays.toString(vertices);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need override `Point.toString()`.

When you using `System.out.println(p);` you're actually using `System.out.println(p.toString());`

Except for eight basically data types, other object using `System.out.println()` will print their address if you don't override `toString()`